# Joining two parallel branches with a wire

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

[image]

In the above circuit (grounding  the negative terminal of the battery,) will the potential at C and D be the same?

According to my physics teacher, the potential is the same at the two points.

Why is that so?

Also, it turns out if there was a resistor between C and D  as shown:

[image]

The voltages aren't the same.

What's different in this case?

I'm a high school student, so my knowledge aboutt circuits isn't  the best.

Comment: An ideal wire has no resistance and is a conductor which is equipotential.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if you ignore parasitics (wire resistance and capacitive/inductive coupling) i.e. always in high school, two nodes tied by a wire are at the same potential and, in fact, one only node for analysis purpose.

The first circuit is simply the parallel of R1 and R3 in series with the parallel of R2 and R4 and it's trivial to analyze.

There are only 3 nodes:

- The supply
- The intermediate point (nodes C and D)
- The ground

The second circuit has 4 nodes and it's not immediately computable like the first one. There are *many* laws and theorems which help for that (you *will* learn them). C and D are different nodes and have different potential unless you can demonstrate that on the middle resistor flows no current (for example if R1=R3 and R2=R4)

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvmqtg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1.*

- In Figure 1a we have R1 = R2 so the connection point will be half of 10 V = 5 V. Similarly R3 = R4 so their connection point will also be at 5 V. Since both sides are at 5 V there is no potential difference between them and VM1 reads 0 V. You could replace the voltmeter with a wire and nothing would change. No current would flow in the wire because there is no voltage across it.
- In Figure 1b we've changed R6 to 300 Ω. Now the voltage on that side is 3/4 of 10 V (\$ V_{R6} = 10 \frac {300}{100+300} = 7.5 V \$). Meanwhile R7 = R8 so the voltage on R8 will still be 5 V. VM2 will read 2.5 V (although the simulator has come up with 2.485 V for some reason).

If you replace VM2 with a wire current will flow through it and it will affect the current in the two branches.

This circuit is a bit like the Wheatstone Bridge circuit that you will probably learn soon. It relies on you balancing the ratios between two branches of a circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJvcSm.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. The Wheatstone Bridge.*

With one known resistor, R2, a resistance wire, measuring tape and a voltmeter it is possible to calculate the value of the unknown resistor R1. Set up the circuit and move the wiper along the resistance wire until VM1 reads 0 V. Now the ratio of the top portion of wire (L1) to the bottom (L2) = the ratio of R1 to R2.

$$ \frac {L1}{L2} = \frac {R1}{R2} $$
so
$$ R1 = \frac {L1}{L2}R2 $$